# I want to replace a particular occurence of string with another using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like "100MW and 50 MWs". I want to use regex to find all occurrences of "MW" and replace it with say "Hi". So the end result should look like "100Hi and 50 His".

I tried using `replaceAll()`, but I couldn't find get the desired result.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `replaceAll` function doesn't modify the string it's used on, because strings are immutable. What it does is returns a new string with the modifications. Just reassign the return value of the function to the string, like so:

```
String myString = "100MW and 50 MWs";
myString = myString.replaceAll("MW","Hi");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `replace` instead of `replaceAll` . `replaceAll` function would take a `regex` as first argument. You don't actually need a regex here.

```
String str = "100MW and 50 MWs";
str = str.replace("MW", "Hi");
System.out.println(str);
```

And note that, strings are immutable in java. So you need to do the replacement and assign the results  back to the same variable like above.

Output:

```
100Hi and 50 His
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is actually that the OP assumes that the String object mutates when `replace()` is called, and needs to *assign* the value returned back to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Looks prettry straight forward. Try below code

```
String str = "100MW and 50 MWs";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("MW", "Hi"));
```